# A closed form for $\sum_{i\cdot j^k=n}(-1)^i$?

Tags: closed-form, arithmetic-functions

$$\alpha_k(n) \stackrel{\text{def.}}{=} \sum_{i\cdot j^k=n}(-1)^i.$$
Does a closed form exist for $\alpha_k(n)$? For low values of $k$:
$$\alpha_0(n)=(-1)^n$$
$$\alpha_1(n)=\begin{cases}
2\nu_2(n)-\sigma_0\left(\frac{n}{2^{\nu_2(n)}}\right)  & \text{ if n is even, n}\ne2^{m}  \\
\nu_2(n)-1  & \text{ if n is even, n}=2^{m}  \\ 
-\sigma_0(n) & \text{ if n is odd}  
\end{cases}$$
And with $a,b$ odd, $a\ne1$ having no repeated prime factors:
$$\alpha_2(n)=\begin{cases}
\sigma_0(b)p  & \text{ if n=}ab^22^{2p+1}  \\ 
\sigma_0(b)(p-2) & \text{ if n =}ab^22^{2p}  
\end{cases}.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, define $t_k(n)$ for fixed $k\ge 1$ to be the indicator function for the integer powers of $k$.

By definition $t_k(n)$ is multiplicative. In addition let the dirichlet character modulo two be : $\chi_2(n)$.

$$\sum_{ij^k=n}(-1)^i=\sum_{ij^k=n}1-2\chi_2(i)=\sum_{ia=n}t_k(a)(1-2\chi_2(i))=\sum_{d\mid n}t_k(d)-2\sum_{d\mid n}t_k(d)\chi_2(\frac{n}{d})$$
$$=\prod_{p\mid n}(1+\lfloor\frac{v_p(n)}{k}\rfloor)-2\prod_{p\mid n}(\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor{\frac{n}{k}\rfloor}}\chi_2(p^{n-jk}))$$

Where $v_p(n)$ denotes the p-adic order of $n$, which finally gives us that $a_k(n)=$

### $$
\begin{cases}
-\prod\limits_{p\mid n}\left(1+\left\lfloor\frac{v_p(n)}{k}\right\rfloor\right)      & 2 \nmid n\\
\prod\limits_{p\mid n}\left(1+\left\lfloor\frac{v_p(n)}{k}\right\rfloor\right)   &   2 \mid n, k\nmid n
     \\ \left(1-{2}{\left(1+\left\lfloor\frac{v_p(n)}{k}\right\rfloor\right)^{-1}  }\right)\prod\limits_{p\mid n}\left(1+\left\lfloor\frac{v_p(n)}{k}\right\rfloor\right)   & 2 \mid n,k\mid n
\end{cases}$$